# How to exit if a command failed?

Tags: linux, bash, exit, exitstatus

I am a noob in shell-scripting. I want to print a message and exit my script if a command fails. I've tried:

```
my_command && (echo 'my_command failed; exit)
```

but it does not work. It keeps executing the instructions following this line in the script. I'm using Ubuntu and bash.

Comment: Did you intend the unclosed quote to be a syntax error that would cause fail/exit? if not, you should close the quote in your example.

Answer (score 561, accepted):

Try:

```
my_command || { echo 'my_command failed' ; exit 1; }
```

Four changes:

- Change `&&` to `||`
- Use `{ }` in place of `( )`
- Introduce `;` after `exit` and
- spaces after `{` and before `}`

Since you want to print the message and exit only when the command fails ( exits with non-zero value) you need a `||` not an `&&`.

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

will run `cmd2` when `cmd1` succeeds(exit value `0`). Where as

```
cmd1 || cmd2
```

will run `cmd2` when `cmd1` fails(exit value non-zero).

Using `( )` makes the command inside them run in a ***sub-shell*** and calling a `exit` from there causes you to exit the sub-shell and not your original shell, hence execution continues in your original shell.

To overcome this use `{ }`

The last two changes are required by bash.

Comment: It does appear to be "reversed". If a function "succeeds" it returns 0 and if it "fails" it returns non-zero therefore && might be expected to evaluate when the first half returned non-zero.

That does not mean the answer above is incorrect - no it is correct. && and || in scripts work based on success not on the return value.

Comment: It seems reversed, but read it out and it makes sense: "do this command (successfully)" OR "print this error and exit"

Comment: The logic behind it is that the language uses short-circuit evaluation (SCE). With SCE, f the expression is of the form "p OR q", and p is evaluated to be true, then there is no reason to even look at q. If the expression is of the form "p AND q", and p is evaluated to be false, there is no reason to look at q. The reason for this is two-fold: 1) its faster, for obvious reasons and 2) it avoids certain kinds of errors (for example: "if x!=0 AND 10/x > 5" will crash if there is no SCE). The ability to use it in the command line like this is a happy side-effect.

Comment: I would recommend echoing to STDERR: `{ (>&2 echo 'my_command failed') ; exit 1; }`

Comment: when I use `exit 1`; it also closes the terminal I am on

Comment: @alper see the answer I've added below

Answer (score 173):

The other answers have covered the direct question well, but you may also be interested in using `set -e`. With that, any command that fails (outside of specific contexts like `if` tests) will cause the script to abort. For certain scripts, it's very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's also very dangerous -- `set -e` has a long and arcane set of rules about when it works and when it doesn't. (If anyone runs `if yourfunction; then ...`, then `set -e` will never fire inside `yourfunction` or anything it calls, because that code is considered "checked"). See [the exercises section of BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), discussing this and other pitfalls (some of which only apply to specific shell versions, so you need to be sure to test against every release that might be used to run your script).

Answer (score 119):

If you want that behavior for all commands in your script, just add

```
set -e 
set -o pipefail
```

at the beginning of the script. This pair of options tell the bash interpreter to exit whenever a command returns with a non-zero exit code. (For more details about why `pipefail` is needed, see http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/11/pipefail.html)

This does not allow you to print an exit message, though.

Comment: You can run commands on exit using the `trap` bash built-in command.

Comment: This is the answer to the X-Y question.

Comment: Might be interesting to explain what commands do independently rather than the pair. Especially since `set -o pipefail` might not be the desired behavior. Still thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: `set -e` is not at all reliable, consistent or predictable! To convince yourself of that, review the exercises section of [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), or the table comparing different shells' behaviors at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/

Comment: A one liner: `set -euo pipefail`

Answer (score 83):

Note also, each command's exit status is stored in the shell variable $?, which you can check immediately after running the command. A non-zero status indicates failure:

```
my_command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "it worked"
else
    echo "it failed"
fi
```

Comment: This can just be replaced by if my_command, there is no need to use the test command here.

Comment: +1 because I think you oughtn't be punished for listing this alternative - it should be on the table - though it's kinda ugly and in my experience too easy to run another command in between without noticing the nature of the test (maybe I'm just stupid).

Comment: @BartSas If the command is long, it's better to put it on its own line.  It makes the script more readable.

Comment: @Michael, not if it creates dependencies across lines, where you need to know what happened on line A before you can understand line B (or, worse, need to know what's going to happen in line B before you know it's safe to add something new after the end of line A). I've seen too many times someone added a `echo "Just finished step A"`, not knowing that that `echo` overwrote the `$?` that was going to be checked later.

Answer (score 18):

Provided `my_command` is canonically designed, *ie* returns 0 when succeeds, then `&&` is exactly the opposite of what you want. You want `||`.

Also note that `(` does not seem right to me in bash, but I cannot try from where I am. Tell me.

```
my_command || {
    echo 'my_command failed' ;
    exit 1; 
}
```

Comment: IIRC, you need semicolons after each of the lines inside {}

Comment: @Alex: not if they're on separate line.

Answer (score 17):

I've hacked up the following idiom:

```
echo "Generating from IDL..."
idlj -fclient -td java/src echo.idl
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then { echo "Failed, aborting." ; exit 1; } fi

echo "Compiling classes..."
javac *java
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then { echo "Failed, aborting." ; exit 1; } fi

echo "Done."
```

Precede each command with an informative echo, and follow each command with that same
 `if [ $? -ne 0 ];...` line.  (Of course, you can edit that error message if you want to.)

Comment: This could be defined as a function, thus reuse it.

Comment: 'if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then ... fi' is a complicated way to write '||'

Comment: `if ! javac *.java; then ...` -- why bother with `$?` at all?

Comment: Charles -- because I am a mediocre bash scripter at best :)

Answer (score 15):

You can also use, if you want to preserve exit error status, and have a readable file with one command per line:

```
my_command1 || exit
my_command2 || exit
```

This, however will not print any additional error message. But in some cases, the error will be printed by the failed command anyway.

Comment: There's no reason for it to be `exit $?`; just `exit` uses `$?` as its default value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy didn't know. Awesome, so it's even simpler!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I applied your suggestion

Answer (score 6):

The `trap` shell builtin allows catching signals, and other useful conditions, including failed command execution (i.e., a non-zero return status). So if you don't want to explicitly test return status of every single command you can say `trap "your shell code" ERR` and the shell code will be executed any time a command returns a non-zero status. For example:

`trap "echo script failed; exit 1" ERR`

Note that as with other cases of catching failed commands, pipelines need special treatment; the above won't catch `false | true`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `exit` directly may be tricky as the script may be sourced from other places (e.g. from terminal). I prefer instead using subshell with `set -e` (plus errors should go into cerr, not cout) :

```
set -e
ERRCODE=0
my_command || ERRCODE=$?
test $ERRCODE == 0 ||
    (>&2 echo "My command failed ($ERRCODE)"; exit $ERRCODE)
```