# jenkins continues deploy process, although NPM fails installing modules

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I've got a deploy process set up in jenkins, which first installs the entire JavaScript app locally on the jenkins server, starts grunt for testing/building the app, and copies everything over to a staging machine afterwards.

Yesterday I noticed that I had a typo in my package.json and npm failed to install an updated module, thus throwing a warning.

Jenkins seems to have noticed that issue and marked the build as UNSTABLE, but kept on deploying (Post-Build tasks using ssh-copy plugin).

Is there a way to stop a build process when NPM fails to install a module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try

```
npm install || exit 1
```

What this command says is if the "npm install" command didn't run successfully (didn't return exit code of 0) then "exit 1"

For reference:
[How to exit if a command failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822621/how-to-exit-if-a-command-failed)

Comment: Please provide further details about how this could solve the problem of the user.